# Ruby on Rails, google charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I am using [googlecharts gem](http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/) for Ruby. And I want to plot a histogram of cars with different column colors and a vertical axis range. Somehow all columns have the same color and the axis label does not work as well.
Where is my mistake?

```
 <%= image_tag(Gchart.bar :size => '340x260', 
                   :title => 'Car Types',
                   :data => [5,1,10],
                   :legend => ['BWM','Audi','Opel'],
                   :bar_colors => '3300CC,3399FF,33CCFF',
                   :axis_with_labels =>'y',                   
                   :axis_labels =>[0,10]



                   ) %>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: All the bar color examples show nested arrays, so maybe try this? `:data => [[5],[1],[10]]`

Comment: and what is with labels?

Comment: Did you try it without the `axis_labels` parameter? It looks like it might generate scales for you when you don't pass a custom label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
<%= image_tag(Gchart.bar :size => '340x260', 
                   :stacked => false,
                   :title => 'Car Types',
                   :data => [[5],[1],[10]],
                   :legend => ['BWM','Audi','Opel'],
                   :bar_colors => ['3300CC','3399FF','33CCFF'],
                   :axis_with_labels => ['y'],                   
                   :axis_labels => [[0,10]]
                   ) %>
```